# Jquery If statement to keep loop

Tags: jquery, events, click

I have these two Jquery click events that will hide/display each other's buttons but it doesn't loop. Should i use Jquery 'toggle' event?
thanks!!

```
        // Desktop onclick function to re-display first 2 drop down lists
        $editDeskBtn.on('click', function () {
            $disDeskSel1.fadeOut();
            $disDeskSel2.fadeOut();
            $firstTwoInputs
                .css("display", "block")
                .hide()
                .fadeIn();
            $editDeskBtn.replaceWith($saveDeskBtn);
            $saveDeskBtn.css("display", "block");

        });
        // *******************************************************************

    // Desktop onclick function for SAVE button
    $saveDeskBtn.on('click', function () {
        $firstTwoInputs.fadeOut();
        // show first two input results
        $disDeskSel1.fadeIn();
        $disDeskSel2.fadeIn();
        $saveDeskBtn.replaceWith($editDeskBtn);
        $editDeskBtn.css("display", "block");
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't loop"?

Comment: I'm still thinking about "it doesn't loop". The code *looks* well but we have to see these variable assignments.

Comment: well when the second button displays it doesnt hide or display the other button onclick. just stops and the button doesnt trigger any events

Comment: @Barmar's answer is correct. You can replace `.css('display', 'block')` by `.show()` or `.hide()` in each case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your use of `replaceWith`. When you replace an element, all its event bindings are lost.

Instead of replacing elements, just keep both elements in the DOM, and use `.hide` and `.show` to show the one that you want.

```
$editDeskBtn.on('click', function () {
    $disDeskSel1.fadeOut();
    $disDeskSel2.fadeOut();
    $firstTwoInputs.hide().fadeIn();
    $editDeskBtn.hide();
    $saveDeskBtn.show();

});
// *******************************************************************

// Desktop onclick function for SAVE btn
$saveDeskBtn.on('click', function () {
    $firstTwoInputs.fadeOut();
    // show first two input results
    $disDeskSel1.fadeIn();
    $disDeskSel2.fadeIn();
    $saveDeskBtn.hide();
    $editDeskBtn.show();
});
```

I've also replaced all your `.css` calls with `.show` and `.hide`.

If you really need to use `replaceWith`, use event delegation as described in [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: Thanks! yea thats great. The reason i used replace was because the buttons are bouncing in the parent container. i tried to use absolute positioning but it doesnt seem to work

Comment: If you really need to use replace, see the link to the question about event delegation.